# Homestead Installation, Vagrant up command is not working

Tags: ruby, vagrant, homestead

I am facing following error when running the command

```
$ vagrant up
```

> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 7 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)

I tried to replace tabs in Homestead.yaml file with spaces, but it is still not working..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run `bash init.sh` from `~/Homestead` in a git bash to reset all the changes you've done so far to the `Homestead.yaml` file and then check the path for `authorize:` and `Keys:` in `Homestead.yaml` file to make sure they match the public and private key in your `~/.ssh` folder, my problem was there.